# iOS Control Center/Notifications Center can't be shown after opening the app by tapping the push notification

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification

I use iOS 10 and hidden application status bar and have a problem as described in question title.

**Steps to reproduce:**

1) User tap the push notification, and app will open

2) User swiped down on the status bar/swiped up at the bottom of the screen to show the notifications center/control center

**Actual Result**: Control Center/Notifications Center can't be shown after opening the app by tapping the push notification.

Please, help me if you have the same problem or know how to fix it.

Comment: This sounds like the expected behaviour. Once a user taps a notification for an app all other notifications for that app are cleared.

Comment: I edit question: application have a hidden status bar. Can it cause this problem?

Comment: Other application with visible status bar allow for user to swipe down a Notifications center panel

Comment: AFAIK, for apps without status bar (i.e. games) first swipe will show a kind of a "handle" - you need to touch it and pull it down/up to show notification/control center. This "handle" is visible only for a short time, and may be hard to notice if you have dark background in your app.